# Unable to run % python help(sys) in zsh on MacOS

Tags: python, zsh

I'm going through free Google Python training course. Real basic stuff. My OS is MacOS. Using MacOS Terminal. I can run python modules like hello.py.
I can run this to see my version:

```
% python --version
Python 3.9.12
```

However, this fails:

```
% python help(sys)
zsh: unknown file attribute: y
```

What do I need to change in my setup to resolve and be able to call simple help in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parentheses have a special meaning in zsh, so they must be escaped here to pass the argument as-is to Python. You can use `\` in front of the parentheses (`python help\(sys\)`), but  it's conventional to just quote the entire argument:

```
python 'help(sys)'
```

However, this still won't work (because the `python` command interprets it as a filename), you need to pass code via the `-c` flag to Python:

```
python -c 'help(sys)'
```

And that still won't work since you haven't loaded the `sys` package in that code. Do that, to get working code:

```
python -c 'import sys; help(sys)'
```

Comment: python 'help(sys)' > [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @Jason Did you read my *entire* answer?

Comment: python -c 'help(sys)' > File "<string>", line 1, in <module> NameError name 'sys' is not defined.

Comment: @Jason ... did you read my **entire** answer?!

Comment: python -c 'import sys; help(sys)' WORKED!

Answer (score 0):

Konrad is right, but you are likely looking for a way to start Python interactive shell and execute statements there.

```
 % python
Python 3.10.7 (main, Sep 15 2022, 01:52:03) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> help(sys)
```